# Playing MP4 videos from a website in iPad vs. iPhone?

Tags: ipad, video

Are there certain formatting requirements or minimum resolution requirements for a video to play in an iPad? I had presumed that any video that would play in an iPhone would also play in an iPad.

But I have a website that includes videos. For browsers, these videos are displayed using Flash Video. These videos are also converted into MP4 files for playback on mobile devices.

Users can view our videos just fine using the iPhone and iPod Touch, but when someone goes to view the same video using the iPad it won't play the video.

What gives?

Comment: Are you able/willing to divulge a link so we can inspect the content and it's encoding formats?

Answer (score 1):

Does the browser location actually end with ".mp4" and you get the Can't Play (play triangle with the slash through it) icon?

Who set up the site? It's possible that it is serving MP4s for "mobile" devices like the iPhone, but the full Flash site for the iPad.